# Your Apple ID isn't enabled for iTunes Connect. Learn More?

Tags: macos, itunes

I tried to login to itunes connect with my apple ID. I can login to https://developer.apple.com/membercenter/index.action#progSummary

When I try to login to

https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/wo/1.0

I got

```
Your Apple ID isn't enabled for iTunes Connect. Learn More
```

I tried to sign up to itunes connect but to no avail.

What exactly should I do?

Someone said they need to contact apple. How to do so?

Note: I already search google.

Comment: Have you solved that issue? I have same here.

Answer (score -1):

Have you enrolled in the Apple Developer Program? Here's the link: https://developer.apple.com/programs/

If you're not sure, note that it's $100/year to be in the program. If you've paid the $100 then you're in and you should have access to iTunes Connect.

Being able to log into the Apple Developer website doesn't mean you're in the Apple Developer program ;)